# Woocommerce get product subtotal in cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to implement ajax functionality to my cart page for updating quantity. So far so good. But I am stuck at one point - updating the product subtotal. I was trying to use this : `get_product_subtotal($_product, $quantity)`, but could not succeed. Because the 1st argument ($_product) is an object. I don't know how to get that. I can get product id and quantity which I passed with ajax call. Now I need the project object with the id. Can anyone help with solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create product object with the following code

```
$product = new WC_Product( $product_id );
```